# what is primordial class loader? How it is used in Java?

Tags: java, classloader

I was studying the Java architecture and in between, I found a concept of class loader and it was also referenced as a primordial class loader. I want to know that what is the function of this class loader, why we use this? I also want to know that what was the basic need so that we are using this.

Answer (score 6):

In Java every class has to be loaded by some class loader.

How is the first class loaded? It has to be loaded through some class loader (which is just another class), so without some special code this would lead to infinity recursion.

The class loader that loads the first classes (`java.lang.Object`, `java.lang.Class`, `java.lang.String`, `java.lang.ClassLoader` and others) can therefore not be a 'normal' class loader.

It is this class loader that is referenced as the primordial class loader (primordial: from latin, meaning "the first", "the origin(al)")

For further study see the [Java Security Aritecture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/spec/security-spec.doc5.html#a28414) and Securing Java

Answer (score 0):

**Primordial** class loader the first class loader responsible to load class loader like "BootStrap class loader" which is part of JVM and written in native language.